# batch not displaying full filename

Tags: batch-file, registry, associations, filenames

I am currently playing with batch and associations.
Why is it that %0 to get full path of the batch file and %1 won't fully display a filename (if more than 1 word spaced) properly.

-reg file entered into registry-

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\show me path\command]
@="\"C:\\blah\\blah\\sample batch.bat\"%1"
```

-sample batch.bat-

```
@echo off
echo %0
echo %1
pause
```

Results from right click command "show me path" of file "try this.mp4"

```
"c:\blah\blah\sample batch.bat"
c:\try
press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see I get "try" how to get it to display full path/file name

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your key to

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\show me path\command]
@="\"C:\\blah\\blah\\sample batch.bat\" \"%1\""
```

To check all command line batch was called, use `ECHO %*`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
echo "%~f1"
```

but this maybe will fail.